# What the syntax HAVING COUNT(*) >1 is doing in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, having

I found this syntax in a online course. I do understand it. But how it works? I do not understand the `HAVING COUNT (*) > 1`. Does it mean count the rows of the table in my view?

```
SELECT M1.title, m1.director
FROM       MOVIE as M1
INNER JOIN MOVIE as M2   ON M1.director = M2.director
GROUP BY m1.mID, m1.title, m1.director
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY m1.director, m1.title;
```

Comment: "The HAVING clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword cannot be used with aggregate functions.", quoted from https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: It's filtering on the result of GROUP BY

Comment: The result contains only results where the combination of mID, title and directory occurs more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your example it is returning rows where the `GROUP BY` row count is greater than one. Note greater than not equal to.

The `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` clause retrieves the results for the specified group, which match the conditions in the `HAVING` clause.

The `HAVING` clause is used with `COUNT()`instead of a `WHERE` clause.

Now see the below example, I have used simple data and ordered it to help with the explanation.

You have the below query and are applying to the table TeamMember

```
SELECT FirstName,COUNT(*) 
FROM TeamMember 
GROUP BY FirstName
HAVING COUNT(*)>3
```

TeamMember

```
+------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| StaffCode  | FirstName            | LastName           |
+------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| 2343       | Alex                 | Jones              |
| 7323       | Alex                 | Paker              |
| 5676       | Alex                 | York               |
| 6571       | Alex                 | Long               |
| 5325       | Paul                 | Thomas             |
| 5365       | Paul                 | Wanye              |
| 5345       | Paul                 | Large              |
| 3543       | Tom                  | Lee                |
| 2311       | Tom                  | Freeman            |
| 5434       | Zac                  | Rogers             |
+------------+----------------------+--------------------+
```

This is what happens as the causes are added.

Adding the `GROUP BY FirstName`

```
+----------------------+--------------------+
| FirstName            | COUNT(*)           |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Alex                 | 4                  |
| Paul                 | 3                  |
| Tom                  | 2                  |
| Zac                  | 1                  |
+----------------------+--------------------+
```

Now adding `HAVING COUNT(*)>3`

```
+----------------------+--------------------+
| FirstName            | COUNT(*)           |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Alex                 | 4                  |
+----------------------+--------------------+
```

I have included the below link for further reference if required.

[Further information](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-having.php)